# Apache Camel : capture body from cxf consumer endpoint in header

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement where the request payload of a web service has to be used in multiple activities in the route. In my specific case, the incoming request is used for performing two xsl transformations. 
To be able to access the original payload, I am trying to put that into a header, but as soon as I try to set the header on the payload, it throws exception related to START_ELEMENT / END_ELEMENT

My route :

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="loadGlobalVars">
        <camel:from id="_from1" uri="direct:LoadGlobalVariables"/>
        <camel:setHeader headerName="_globalVariables" id="_setHeader1">
            <camel:simple resultType="org.w3c.dom.Document">resource:classpath:GlobalVars.xml</camel:simple>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:setHeader headerName="GetValidationCodes" id="_setValidationCodes">
            <camel:simple resultType="org.w3c.dom.Document">resource:classpath:ValidationCodes.xml</camel:simple>
        </camel:setHeader>
    </route>
    <camel:route id="loanServiceRoute">
        <from id="getTransactionDtls" uri="cxf:bean:loanService?dataFormat=PAYLOAD&amp;loggingFeatureEnabled=true"/>
         <camel:setHeader headerName="originalBody">
            <camel:simple resultType="org.w3c.dom.Document">${body}</camel:simple>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:to id="_loadHeaders" uri="direct:LoadGlobalVariables"/>
        <camel:to id="ValidateRequest" uri="xslt:xslt/ValidateTransactionReq.xsl?saxon=true"/>
        <camel:setHeader headerName="ValidationOutput" id="_setHeader2">
            <camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:to id="UseCaseSelection" uri="xslt:xslt/UseCaseTypeSelection.xsl?saxon=true"/>
        <camel:log id="_log1" message="Output from xslt  : ${body}"/>
        <removeHeaders id="_removeHeaders1" pattern="*"/>
    </camel:route>
</camelContext>
```

If I remove the following set header then no exception is thrown.

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="_globalVariables" id="_setHeader1">
        <camel:simple resultType="org.w3c.dom.Document">resource:classpath:GlobalVars.xml</camel:simple>
    </camel:setHeader>
```

Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current event not START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getNamespaceURI(BasicStreamReader.java:799)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthXMLStreamReader.getNamespaceURI(DepthXMLStreamReader.java:130)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthXMLStreamReader.getNamespaceURI(DepthXMLStreamReader.java:130)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxSource.parse(StaxSource.java:113)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxSource.parse(StaxSource.java:268)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:451)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:153)
at net.sf.saxon.Controller.makeSourceTree(Controller.java:1917)
at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:573)
at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:185)
at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltBuilder.process(XsltBuilder.java:141)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:103)
at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.onExchange(XsltEndpoint.java:131)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$CxfConsumerInvoker.asyncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:156)
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$CxfConsumerInvoker.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:133)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1129)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am trying to understand, how can just setting a header make the route go into errors?

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that I was able to find an answer. For other who might wonder about this same question.

The cxf component generates a stream type for the payload ( this is my assumption but most probably this is the case). By nature, i can read a stream only once, hence, when i try to use it again i get the exception.

You can add streamCache=true and that will enable to use ready it as many number of times.

For more details refer to : http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html